# What are movies called that are recorded at the same place?

Tags: genre

I wonder what is the specific term used or what are those movies like *127 Hours* called that are recorded at the same place?

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/17189/49.

Comment: ..... as in they are recorded all in one place / set.  Or recorded in a real location?  I think you mean set in one location, but just checking.

Answer (score 3):

I don't work in the film industry, so am happy to accept I could be wrong, but I don't think there is an "official" term for this. I think colloquially it is simply known as a **one-location film**.

[This article](http://microbudgetfeatures.com/a-look-at-one-location-films/) discusses some of the benefits and reasons for doing them:

> The idea of making a film in one location is both tempting and
>   horrifying for filmmakers. On one side, there is an immense production
>   advantage: costs across the spectrum are considerably reduced and in
>   some cases virtually eliminated. The production team only needs to
>   secure, light, and art direct one location, and there is no longer a
>   need to spend money transporting crew, cast and equipment from one
>   location to another. Furthermore, shooting time and crew size are
>   minimized as a result of the narrow production demands. Thus, shooting
>   in one location may guarantee a low production cost without
>   sacrificing production value.  On the other side, setting a film on
>   one location presents creative challenges to the writer, the director,
>   and the production team that could potentially trigger the failure of
>   the film and are not as present in films designed to take place in
>   multiple locations.
>
> To create a successful one-location film – a feature shot in one or
>   mostly one location – a writer needs to construct a plot that must be
>   entertaining, meaningful and cinematic, confined within four physical
>   walls. A director must invoke a performance from his/her actors that
>   shows progression and change in character without the option of
>   changing their environment. In doing so he/she must also stay faithful
>   to the medium by using character interaction rather than theatrical
>   monologues to reveal internal conflict and transformation. The
>   director, together with the production design team and
>   cinematographer, need to develop a visual strategy to keep the
>   audience interested and focused; avoiding repetition of shots and not
>   being deliberate. The combination of these techniques must as a whole
>   convey to the audience that by the end of the film the actors are, but
>   are not, in the same place where the film started.
>
> One-location films have been attempted on both the micro-budget and
>   the studio level. In both cases, there have been those that have
>   captivated audiences and critics, and those that have fallen flat...